# Determine if a list of files exist in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm a newbie, and the monads get me totally confused. Given a list of filenames i'd like to know whether all the files exist.

Generally, i'd like to do:

```
import System.Directory
allFilesPresent files = foldr (&&) True (map doesFileExist files)
```

However i do not know what's the right way to do it, because there's `IO Bool` instead of `Bool` involved here.

A help with and explanation would be really nice, thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that `foldr (&&) True` is the function Prelude.and .

Comment: I strongly suggest reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output You can then read some of the other chapters on Functors, Applicative, Monoids, and Monads. Very gentle and gradual introduction to these topics.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right, your code doesn't work because `map doesFileExist files` returns a list of `IO Bool`s instead of `Bool`. To fix this, you can use `mapM` instead of `map`, which will give you an `IO [Bool]`. You can the unpack that using `>>=` or `<-` inside a `do`-block and then use `foldr (&&)` on the unpacked `[Bool]` and `return` that. The result will be an `IO Bool`. Like this:

```
import System.Directory
allFilesPresent files = mapM doesFileExist files >>=
                        return . foldr (&&) True
```

Or using do notation:

```
import System.Directory
allFilesPresent files = do bools <- mapM doesFileExist files
                           return $ foldr (&&) True bools
```

Or using `liftM` from `Control.Monad`:

```
allFilesPresent files = liftM (foldr (&&) True) $ mapM doesFileExist files
```

Or using `<$>` from `Control.Applicative`:

```
allFilesPresent files = foldr (&&) True <$> mapM doesFileExist files
```

Comment: Don't forget `foldr (&&) True == and` (or near enough for this use case)

Comment: Or if you're comfortable installing Haskell libraries, the monad-loops library has a function `allM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m Bool` in the `Control.Monad.Loops` module.  With that function, `allFilesPresent = allM doesFileExist`

Answer (score 6):

`doesFileExist "foo.txt"` is an `IO Bool`, which means its result depends on the state of the outside world.

You're on the right track with `map doesFileExist files` -- this expression will return `[IO Bool]`, or a list of world-dependent expressions. What's actually needed is an `IO` expression containing a list of bools. You can get this using `sequence`:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

or, since you're just using sequence/map, the `mapM` helper function:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM f xs = sequence (map f xs)
```

Lets go back to your code. Here's a version using `mapM`, with comments:

```
import System.Directory

-- When figuring out some unfamiliar libraries, I like to use type annotations
-- on all top-level definitions; this will help you think through how the types
-- match up, and catch errors faster.
allFilesPresent :: [String] -> IO Bool

-- Because allFilesPresent returns a computation, we can use do-notation to write
-- in a more imperative (vs declarative) style. This is sometimes easier for students
-- new to Haskell to understand.
allFilesPresent files = do

    -- Run 'doesFileExist' tests in sequence, storing the results in the 'filesPresent'
    -- variable. 'filesPresent' is of type [Bool]
    filesPresent <- mapM doesFileExist files

    -- The computation is complete; we can use the standard 'and' function to join the
    -- list of bools into a single value.
    return (and filesPresent)
```

An alternative version uses more declarative syntax; this is probably what an experienced Haskell programmer would write:

```
allFilesPresent :: [String] -> IO Bool
allFilesPresent = fmap and . mapM doesFileExist
```

Comment: I think you mean `allFilesPresent = fmap and . mapM doesFileExist`

Comment: It's not accurate to say that an `IO T` is a `T` that depends on the world.  It's a *recipe* for getting a `T`, which could be executed more than once and produce a different result each time.  Recipes and cakes are totally different kinds of thing.

Comment: @keegan: agreed, and to elaborate on that metaphor, the final product of _executing_ a cake recipe is the thing that I would call a cake that depends on the prior state of the world.  From any given recipe (IO Cake) many such cakes can be created.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you use `sequence` or `mapM`, you are choosing not to short-circuit; even if one of the files turns out not to exist, you still check the rest of the files for existence.  If you want to short-circuit, the following works:

```
import System.Directory

andM :: Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool
andM [] =
    return True
andM (m : ms) = do
    b <- m
    if b then
      andM ms
     else
      return False

allFilesPresent :: [FilePath] -> IO Bool
allFilesPresent files = andM $ map doesFileExist files
```

Or equivalently by using [monad-loops package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.3.1.1):

```
import System.Directory
import Control.Monad.Loops

allFilesPresent :: [FilePath] -> IO Bool
allFilesPresent = allM doesFileExist
```